# HIVE: Finding running total excluding duplicates

Tags: hive, cumulative-sum

Hi I have a very peculiar problem at hand for which I am unable to find a solution. I have a table UserViews having following columns:

```
Progdate(String)
UserName(String)
```

Dummy data in the table:

```
Progdate    UserName
20161119    A
20161119    B
20161119    C
20161119    B
20161120    D
20161120    E
20161120    A
20161121    B
20161121    A
20161121    B
20161121    F
20161121    G
```

Each time a User views a program there is an entry in the table. For example on 19th Nov, User A watched the program once so there is one entry. User B watched the program twice so there are two entries for this user on 19th Nov and so on.

```
Select Progdate, count(distinct UserName) UniqueUsersByDate 
from UserViews 
group by Progdate;
```

Above query will give me date-wise count of all the unique users who have watched the program

```
Progdate    UniqueUsersByDate
20161119    3
20161120    3
20161121    4
```

Below query:

```
Select Progdate, UniqueUsersByDate, Sum(UniqueUsersByDate) over(Order By Progdate) RunningTotalNewUsers
from
(
Select Progdate, count(distinct UserName) UniqueUsersByDate
from 
UserViews 
group by Progdate SORT BY Progdate
) UV;
```

Will give me result as:

```
Progdate    UniqueUsersByDate   RunningTotalNewUsers
20161119    3                   3
20161120    3                   6
20161121    4                   10
```

But what I want is the running total of all the users who have watched the program only first time. Means if User A has watched the program on 20161119 and then again on 20161120, then the count of this User should not be repeated in the running total for 20161120. Thus the result which I want from the above table is:

```
Progdate    UniqueUsersByDate   RunningTotalNewUsers
20161119        3               3
20161120        3               5
20161121        4               7
```

I am looking for the solution only in HIVE HQL. Any input toward the problem is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason you are storing dates as string and more than that, in a non ISO format?

Comment: The database is already created. I do not have any say in it :( I have to just work with what is existing. BTW, this is just a scaled down version of the actual table. Actual table has around 50+ columns. I have just posted the relevant once to make it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select      Progdate
           ,UniqueUsersByDate
           ,sum(Users1stOcc) over
            (
                order by    Progdate
            )                           as RunningTotalNewUsers

from       (select      Progdate
                       ,count (distinct UserName)           as UniqueUsersByDate
                       ,count (case when rn = 1 then 1 end) as Users1stOcc

            from       (select  Progdate
                               ,UserName
                               ,row_number() over
                                (
                                    partition by    UserName
                                    order by        Progdate
                                )   as rn

                        from    UserViews
                        ) uv

            group by    Progdate
            ) uv
;
```

---

```
+-------------+--------------------+-----------------------+
|  progdate   | uniqueusersbydate  | runningtotalnewusers  |
+-------------+--------------------+-----------------------+
| 2016-11-19  | 3                  | 3                     |
| 2016-11-20  | 3                  | 5                     |
| 2016-11-21  | 4                  | 7                     |
+-------------+--------------------+-----------------------+
```

P.s.
Theoretically, the aggregation and the use of the SUM analytical function do not require additional sub-query, but there seems to be an issue (bug/feature) with the parser.
Please note that an additional sub-query does not necessarily indicate an additional execution stage, e.g. `select * from (select * from (select * from (select * from (select * from t)t)t)t)t;` and `select * from t` will have the same execution plan.

Comment: The query designed by you gives answer as expected. The query is complex and it will take some time for me to digest and understand. Some explanation would have helped in understanding. Nevertheless, thanks for your help.